# Issues with divs in pushed footer

Tags: html, css

I'm creating my first website and i'm a newbie. I'm having problems with the elements in my footer. One of the two divs and the image (div="legal-icon") (div="legal") go under the first(div id="cpright"), while resizing the browser window, until they go out of the container. I set overflow to hidden but the result is that the divs that go down disappear and that the first div (id="cpright") is cut in half. How to make the footer elements responsive and correct displayed? Here's a js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/usernamenn/qa4ng6fj/

```
<!-- footer -->
    <div class="footer">
      <!-- footer info --> 
      <div class="copyright">
        <div id="cpright">
        Copyright &copy 2015 - MyWebsite - 
        </div>
      <div class="legal">
        <ul id="legal_links">
          <li><a href="#">Terms of use</a></li>
          <hr>
          <li><a href="#">Privacy policy</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="legal_icon">
          <img id="legal_balance" src="images/balance-scale.png"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- end footer info -->
    </div

.wrapper {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -6em;
}

.footer, .push {
height: 6em;
} 

.footer {
    background-color: #3b3b3b;
    border-top: 3px solid grey;
    overflow: hidden;
 }

#cpright {
    float: left;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: larger;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-left: 100px;
} 

.legal {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 100px;
}

#legal_links ul {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#legal_links li {
    display: block;
}

#legal_links li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

#legal_links a:hover {
    color: lightgray;
}

.legal_icon {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 65px;
    right: 20px;    
}

#legal_balance {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
}
```

Comment: Try to use more common practice. For example: Use the footer element instead of div's... it makes it a lot easier to read and find issues. Also: be sure to know when you have to use classes, and when to use id's.

As for the problem, it's in the css. So posting your CSS (and not just in JSFiddle) would be better. Note: You're using a !important, that's bad practise, try to search for alternatives. Last but not least: Keep the names clean. Try not to shorten it like cpright, when copyright is almost the same but way easier to read and understand.

Comment: Ah ok. i used shorter names because I saw it in a tutorial. You mean using the -footer in which way? i have to remove all the divs and place everything in the footer element?

Comment: Do you want the two elements to stay besides each other? Or do you want the footer height to resize and place the terms below the copyright? If the latter, do you want them to align centered on the page?

Comment: you should use display flex on your parent footer and give `space between property to align items.` It will be helpful. And in media query you can just  align to block.

Comment: Jazzro, i want the latter option you suggested with the div aligned to the center of the page.

Comment: Have a look at flexbox:https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
What I meant is the footer element <footer> instead of using a div giving a classname. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_footer.asp
This keeps it clean :)

Comment: Thanks i'm going to watch this and to learn how to fix this bug. I'm at the fourth day with this footer and i'm going mad,

Comment: The problem with the unclean sintax of the html code of my footer is not my fault. I download the code of the footer from the internet and then i tried to rearrange that to my needs.

Comment: Try searching for the term 'sticky footer' to look for tutorials. I saw another post of you, using the footer element. This indicates to me that you still copy a lot. Please be sure to understand the basics of HTML. Creating elements, using attributes, when to use class/id etc. Do not try to recreate the best website you've ever seen, try to learn how it works first :) Make ik functional, not fancy just yet! :) Syntax and readable code is more important than whatsoever :)

Comment: I don't say it's the problem, I'm only giving you advice on how to do things better. You will be able to solve it once you learned the basics. ;)

Comment: If what you want to do is to let the footer grow with its content, the solution would be as easy as to remove the footer from this rule: `.footer, .push { height: 6em; }` (or maybe replacing the `height` for a `min-height` so it would have a height of at least 6em)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want to do is make the footer grow vertically, the solution would be as easy as to remove the specified `height`. Right now you have this:

```
.footer, .push {
    height: 6em;
}
```

That forces the footer to have a height of 6em, and as its content occupies more space than that, it is cut. A quick solution: [remove that rule from your CSS](https://jsfiddle.net/qa4ng6fj/3/):

```
.footer, .push {
    /* height: 6em; */
}
```

But I don't know if you are using `.push` somewhere else, so another option would be to [remove `.footer` in that particular rule selector](https://jsfiddle.net/qa4ng6fj/4/):

```
.push {
    height: 6em;
}
```

Or [modify the property so it doesn't have a height of 6em but a minimum height of 6em](https://jsfiddle.net/qa4ng6fj/5/):

```
.footer, .push {
    min-height: 6em;
}
```

Although this last one would affect `.push` too, and you may not want that, so you may want to [add it as a separate CSS rule](https://jsfiddle.net/qa4ng6fj/6/):

```
.push {
    height: 6em;
}

.footer {
    min-height: 6em;
}
```